# Restrict ODBC setting changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, odbc

I have an ODBC connection created to an IBM server. This connection is used by Excel files to read data from this server. I want to restrict users from changing any of the ODBC settings either in the Excel file or in their control panel. As users can also modify/delete data from server by SQL command.
Please guide me if there is any user rights setting available in Windows XP/7 by which I can restrict users from changing ODBC connection settings in the system.

Comment: I don't think you can, other than *maybe* making the file read-only (although again, this changeable).. The problem reads more like a staffing issue!

Comment: I dont want user to change any ODBC connections of system. As their is option of what type of connections are allowed using the ODBC ie whether it is read only (select) or full access (even update and delete). And if i make excel readonly, then how are they going to refresh the file ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict user from changing ODBC connection of the system only be changing user rights of ODBCAD32.exe from C:\Windows\System32 folder. You have to set rights only for Admin user and remove other rights.